# A simple interpolation using expressions in julia

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I would like to form expressions like

```
julia> ex = :(a[$i,$j] + b[$i,$j])
```

because I am interested in writting a program that it is able to write a system of equations in which the user only gives the structure of them and then that julia writes explicitly the chunk of code involved. More generally, I would like to embed functions in a expression, something like

```
julia> ex = :(a[$myfunc(i,j),$j] + b[$i,$j])
```

Upon evaluating the first line of code, I get

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: i not defined
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:226
```

On the other hand, if I write

```
julia> ex = :(a[i,j] + b[i,j])
:(a[i,j] + b[i,j])

julia> for i in 1:2
           for j in 1:2
               println(eval(ex))
           end
       end
ERROR: UndefVarError: i not defined
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:226
 [inlined code] from ./boot.jl:225
 in anonymous at ./<no file>:4294967295
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:226
```

How is interpolation done in this case?

Answer (score 4):

[`eval`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#[eval()](@ref)-and-effects-1) works at global scope, so it cannot reference any local variables.  What you can do, however, is interpolate that expression into a larger chunk of code that's intended to be executed at the global scope:

```
julia> a = [1 2; 3 4]
       b = [5 6; 7 8]
       ex = :(a[i,j] + b[i,j]);

julia> @eval for i in 1:2
                  for j in 1:2
                      println($ex)
                  end
              end
6
8
10
12
```

The `@eval` macro is a simple shorthand for quoting the passed syntax and passing it along to the `eval()` function.  It'd probably even be better to define a custom function:

```
julia> @eval function f()
              for i in 1:2
                  for j in 1:2
                      println($ex)
                  end
              end
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f()
6
8
10
12
```

The usual caveats about `eval` apply: any passed code can be maliciously crafted to do nefarious or surprising things.  Or just crash the program.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for. I would like to get, e.g. from `a[i]+b[j]` to `a[1]+b[4]`, as a chunk of code, intead of evaluating the contents at a certain value. Yes, it is more to an algebraic manipulation, instead of simple substitution. The reason is that later I want that the program decides to write things like `a[1] + a[4] + b[3]` which can be determined by the user.

Comment: Put it differently, I want to convert an expression like `sum_i=1,n a[i]+ b[i]` in code form, i.e. `a[1]+b[1]`, if `n=1`, or `a[1]+b[1]+a[2]+b[2]` if `n=2`.